# Get the sum of numbers for similar element in a list of object in Dart?

Tags: dart

I need to iterate over a list of object and sum all "num" for every "title"

```
var obj1 = MyObject(tNum: 10, tTitle: 'Hi');
var obj2 = MyObject(tNum: 9, tTitle: 'Hi');
var obj3 = MyObject(tNum: 8, tTitle: 'Hello');
var obj4 = MyObject(tNum: 7, tTitle: 'Hello');
var obj5 = MyObject(tNum: 12, tTitle: 'Good');
var myList = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5];



var myListIter = myList.iterator;
  var initialTitle = '';
  var finalSum = 0;

  while (myListIter.moveNext()) {
    print(myListIter.current);
    if (myListIter.current.title!.compareTo(initialTitle).isEven) {
      finalSum = finalSum + myListIter.current.num!;
    }else{
      print('--- ${myListIter.current.title!} : $finalSum');
    }
  }
}

class MyObject {
  int? num;
  String? title;
  MyObject({tNum, tTitle}) {
    num = tNum;
    title = tTitle;
  }
}
```

The output:

```
--- Hi : 0
--- Hi : 0
--- Hello : 0
--- Hello : 0
--- Good : 0
```

Expected output:

```
--- Hi : 19
--- Hello : 15
--- Good : 12
```

What is the simplest way to do that?
q,nfczej,pvledv;lzecaz

Comment: Sequentially named variables is *always* a code smell.  If the names are related, very likely the values will need some sort of collective processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var myMap = <String, int>{};
  myList.forEach((obj) => myMap[obj.title!] = (myMap[obj.title] ?? 0) + obj.num!);
  print(myMap);
```

Output:

```
{Hi: 19, Hello: 15, Good: 12}
```

Comment: works as a charm!

Comment: do you think there is a way to get the number of occurrence for each element (Hi 2 times, Hello 2 times, Good 1 time)

Comment: The logic is the same like code above, use `1` instead of `obj.num!` only